# running parallel while loops

Tags: c, multithreading

I am working on motor control application, basically when i press a button the motor will run and i am also measuring the motor current while running, so that i can stop the motor if there is any overload.

The problem is i can stop the motor if there is any overload but the response time is more, the program is not reacting for sudden impact.

Is it possible to run two loops parallel so when i switch on the button one loop will measure the current for any overload and the other loop will work on controlling the motor these two loops should work simultaneously, so that i will get the expected response time..

Comment: So what language is this? C, C++, C# or motordriver?

Comment: You could run the necessary loops in separate threads.

Comment: in C language..for TI processor.

Comment: So please just include a C tag if it is just about C.

Comment: @siva in this case, why did you tag it as C++ and even worse, C#?

Comment: If your platform supports pthread then its a trivial task. A minimal C runtime does not support threading. Many embedded platforms does not have thread support. So Please give more info about your platform.

Comment: @Aftnix..the code is written in CCSTUDIO Ti software..its is used to develop and debug.

Answer (score 1):

As  g-makulik posted in a comment, you could use threads. Or you could fall back to an older solution of maintaining a state within a single loop. 
Not sure if the TI you have supports fork() or threads, but if not, something like this becomes a strong contender.

```
int   need_to_monitor_motor = 1;
int   common_switch;          // true if common processing

while ( need_to_monitor_motor )
{
    common_switch = 1;        // allow common processing

    // you may well need to do something to avoid hogging the processor if
    // other processes are running.  Even a minimal nano-sleep.
    //    sched_yield()
    //    usleep()
    sleep_or_processor_release();   

    switch ( motor_state )
    {
       case MOTOR_OFF:
        need_to_monitor_motor = do_motor_off_stuff();
        break;

       case MOTOR_ON:
        need_to_monitor_motor = do_motor_on_stuff();
        break;

       default
        need_to_monitor_motor = trouble__fix_it( &common_switch );
        break;
    }

    if ( common_switch )
    {
        do_common_processing();
    }
}
```

(beware, have not compiled this)

Answer (score 0):

So, you are writing embedded C program for TI processor. Now the question is: do you have OS/multithreading features enabled? Most cheap TI boards don't have this support, and their embedded program ends with endless loop while(1). All actual work is done in the interrupt handlers. In your case, possibly, you can use one or two timers. Initialize them in the beginning of main function, and do everything necessary in the timer interrupt handlers.

So, find TI code sample with timers for your board, and add your own logic to it.